# How to track Product revision History in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Is there any feature to save product revision history for content changes like wordpress post history?

Comment: There is no inbuilt feature available. Magento track the last updated and created time. You can manage this by creating an observer on product save and save the revisions according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you provide some example code ?

Comment: What type of revisions you want to see?

Comment: There are some paid extension similar to wordpress revision history feature https://store.webkul.com/magento2-product-revision-history-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to track inventory change than follow the below mentioned link:
https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/extensions/magento2-inventory-log/